# C++ treating object* as int*

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

I have some code that accepts a pointer to an object, and this has been working fine thus far, however, after some cleanup (I code messy, and then clean up when most of the bugs are gone), a function that accepts a pointer, is now treating the pointer passed to it as an `int*`.

I have checked that I am indeed passing a pointer, and can't seem to figure this one out. Why is this happening?

Here's some code below (highly trimmed down, and I am not sure if I'm allowed to even show a small amount of this code, but I need to figure this out, so sorry if it doesn't make a lot of sense). I've removed sensitive parts of the code, and frankly, parts I feel I'd be in trouble for posting. But the erroneous part of the code was included.

```
template <class T>
class TreeStructure {
    class TreeNode {

        public:
            T data;
            TreeNode<T> * parent;
            TreeNode<T> * left;
            TreeNode<T> * right;
            inline TreeNode(T d) : data(d), parent(0x0), left(0x0), right(0x0) {}
            inline TreeNode(T d,TreeNode<T>* p) : data(d), parent(p), left(0x0), right(0x0) {}
            inline TreeNode(T d,TreeNode<T>* p,TreeNode<T>* l,TreeNode<T>* r) : data(d), parent(p), left(l), right(r) {}
    };

    TreeNode<T>* root;

    // Recursive CRUD operations, used as helpers to public CRUD operations, _delete shown
    inline void _delete(TreeNode<T>* c) {
        if(c != 0x0) {
            _delete(c->left);  // This is where things go wrong, _delete compains of no valid conversion from 'int*' to 'TreeStructure::TreeNode<T>* [with T = int]'
            _delete(c->right);
            delete c;
            _size--;
            // Irrelevant operations down here
        }
    }

    public:
        inline bool remove(T d) {
            // Check if 'd' is in tree, return false if not, get pointer to containing node if so
            TreeNode<T>* node; // This is where we get the reference to the node. Code returns if data isn't found, so if we're here, we know we have a node.
            // _delete is never called if 'd' isn't in the tree, so we can assume its set to a node since we got this far
            _delete(node); // This call is fine, but the recursive calls in _delete fail
        }

};
```

When I call `remove()`, and `remove()` in turn calls `_delete()`, which complains that the node is an `int*` when it is a `TreeNode<int>*`. And I know that whatever is passed to `_delete()` is a `TreeNode<int>*`, and even when recursively called, is guarded against NULL (noop if null). Why is this happening and how do I solve the issue?

Comment: `TreeNode<int>` is not a type, nor is `TreeNode<T>`. `TreeNode` is not a template. Just use `TreeNode`. (`TreeStructure<int>::TreeNode` _is_ a type, but this is not a template. It's a non-template type declared as a child of a template type.) Also, all of the manual deletion headache goes away if you use `std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: A `TreeNode` is not an `int`. And a pointer to a `TreeNode` is not a pointer to an `int`. And you cannot interchange the two. Why is that surprising?

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you created a minimal complete example that reproduced the problem instead of showing a partial excerpt of some proprietary code. What exactly does the error say? And, as an aside, why on earth are you using `0x0` instead of `nullptr`?

Comment: Surely the compiler listed an error about the declaration of these before the function call? You should start at the top of the error list.

Comment: This code gives plenty of compile-time errors before it gets to your suspect line. Please correct this!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. @cdhowie Thanks for the information, I've hardly ever worked with nested classes and I was informed that everything this class needs should be defined in the class itself, so I took it from the different classes (Tree Node and Walker (iterator-ish class)) and changed it to one class with the two nested classes. And unfortunately, I cannot use shared pointers for this one.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know this, as I stated, I am passing a TreeNode pointer to the function, and the function is seeing this pointer to an object as a int pointer. So, nothing suprising about that, really. Please, I said all of this in the question

Comment: @Useless Im sorry, the code is proprietary, so I wasn't sure if I was allowed to post any of it, and Im sure if i had asked it would have been a flat out no. So I posted as much as I thought I could get away with. So ya, I'm sorry about that, I can provide more details regarding the functionality of the class if you want, but I don't think I'm comfortable sharing more code. Sorry again about that

Comment: @chris This was the first reported error, and all the other errors were related to similar functions (create, update, all with the same signature but different names and maybe three lines of code that makes them different)

Comment: @TonyK Im not getting any runtime errors, only compiler errors regarding this function (and the same errors for the similar functions such as create and update). And not to mention, I did say in the question that this was incomplete code, that its proprietary and highly stripped down. I could post more code, but I feel that it would be too much code put out there and violate my NDA

Comment: @cdhowie I'm gonna modify the code to fit your suggestion, and I'll let you know how it goes. If it works, make an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Useless BTW `0x0` instead of `nullptr` because I like the color blue better, and dont want all my keywords to be blue, just for nullptr. Plus, they are functionally the same, so why on earth not?

Comment: @Werlious `nullptr` is only implicitly convertible to a pointer. If you accidentally use `nullptr` to initialize any other type of variable, you'll get a compile-time error. _"Why on earth not?"_ Because it's less safe to use 0x0.

Comment: @cdhowie ahh I get you. That makes sense then Useless and cdhowie. I used to use NULL once upon a time, but it expanded to 0 anyway so I just started putting 0. Then I got attached to the blue-ness of 0 (NULL and nullptr are red in my IDE), and I've been using 0x0 for years since then without issue. But anyway, cdhowie, your solution worked, so if you want to work it into an answer I'll gladly accept. And thank you to everyone for your input

Comment: @cdhowie, quick question, What would a use-case be, where using `0x0` rather than `nullptr`, would bite me in the buttocks? I might just switch to using `nullptr`, but I want to make sure I really need to before I start doing drills on it

Comment: @Werlious, When a function is overloaded to take pointers and ints and you forget the int one exists, intending to call the pointer version. For example, a function taking either an ID or a handle.

Comment: @Werlious 0x0 prefers conversion to numeric types before pointer types, so as chris said, in a scenario where both are acceptable, 0x0 will prefer an integral conversion. nullptr can _only_ be implicitly converted to a pointer type; using it in a context where an integer is required will (correctly) yield a compile-time error.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for that. I can definitely see that biting me later, especially with that little scenario, as parts of this particular code base will have functions that are overloaded for both pointers and template-type data, some of which will be `int`s. And I'm not a psychic, but i can already see the headaches coming off of that one.  So thanks for the heads up and information on that one.

Comment: and thanks @Useless for pointing that out to me

Comment: @cdhowie did you want to post an answer? I can make one and direct the credit to you but I'd rather have you make one so you can get the rep

Comment: @Werlious I've posted an answer; hopefully it's the part of this dialog that actually fixed your problem. I lost track of what the issue really was along the way.

Comment: @cdhowie You got it on point, thank you, accepting it now. And ya, I'm sorry, I have severe ADHD, and in my experience its kind of contagious to those talking to me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't understand what `TreeNode<T>` is because it doesn't name a type; `TreeNode` is not a template.  Use `TreeNode` everywhere you have `TreeNode<T>`.

`TreeNode` implicitly gets `T` from its outer template class, so specifying it in this way isn't even necessary.  To put it another way, `TreeStructure<int>::TreeNode` and `TreeStructure<std::string>::TreeNode` are already different types.

I'm not sure why you get the specific error you get, but I would assume that somewhere in the mess of errors the compiler spit out is it complaining that `TreeNode` is not a template and so the `<T>` suffix doesn't make sense.  It's a longstanding tradition that C and C++ compilers try to forge ahead even after encountering an error and try to make things work.  I think the theory is that the more errors it can raise at once, the fewer compiler invocations you need to make because you could fix multiple errors each run.  In practice, however, it means the compiler is making bad assumptions and then generating errors predicated on those assumptions, so it can also generate a lot of noise.

In C and C++ programming, always pay attention to the *first* error.  Everything after that is likely to be useless noise.